# Почему возникает ошибка "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'TextView.setText()' on a null object reference"?

Tags: java, android

Специально сделал отдельный проект. При нажатии на кнопку вылетает ошибка.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

public Context context;
public Presenter presenter;

public TextView textView;
public EditText editText;
public Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    context = getApplicationContext();
    presenter = new Presenter(context);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.button:
            String text = editText.getText().toString();
            presenter.changeEditTextContent(text);
    }
}

public void changeText (String msg) {
    textView.setText(msg);
}
```

И вот.

```
public class Presenter {
public Context context;
public MainActivity mainActivity;

public Presenter (Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    mainActivity = new MainActivity();
}

public void changeEditTextContent (String message){
    String msg = message + " Hello World!";
    mainActivity.changeText(msg);
}
```

Ошибка в logcat
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.voroxtaxi.devpart.httcallback, PID: 22574
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
   at com.voroxtaxi.devpart.httcallback.MainActivity.changeText(MainActivity.java:47)
   at com.voroxtaxi.devpart.httcallback.Presenter.changeEditTextContent(Presenter.java:20)
   at com.voroxtaxi.devpart.httcallback.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:42)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4848)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20262)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

//

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.button:
            if (editText != null){
                Log.v("tag", "ok");
                String text = editText.getText().toString();
                presenter.changeEditTextContent(text);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: дополните вопрос текстом ошибки (не картинкой)

Comment: дополнил. есть.

Answer (score 1):

Ваша проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь обратиться к разметке экземпляра активити, созданного не системой, но вами. Вами созданная вручную активити не прикреплена к системе, не вызывала методы жизненного цикла, не грузила разметку и её поля-вьюхи, засим, неинициализированы.

Используйте системную активити, не создавайте свою:

```
//mainActivity = new MainActivity();
mainActivity = (MainActivity)context;
```

Comment: это в Presenter сделать? вместо этого mainActivity = new MainActivity(); написать что вы скинули?

Comment: @PavelVorobyov, да, в конструкторе оного.

Comment: ошибку при старте выдает

Comment: @PavelVorobyov, очень не информативно) Какую ошибку? На какой строке? Что в этой строке? Дополните вопрос этой информацией

Comment: сначала ругается на инициализацию mainActivity в презенторе а потом на инициализацию презентора в мэйнактивити

Comment: @PavelVorobyov, т.е. у вас ошибка компиляции? Какая именно? В коде подчёркнуто? Если да - то если мышь навести - что пишет?

Comment: все заработало. я в презентор передавал getApplicationContext(). исправил на this заработало. то что заработало это хорошо. а почему так? понять надо. можете пояснить

Comment: @PavelVorobyov, это оттого, что `getApplicationContext()` - это общий контекст приложения, экземпляр класса `Application`. А `this` - это ссылка на текущий класс, в вашем случае ссылка на `MainActivity`. Оттого у вас и был `ClassCastException` при попытке скастовать `Application` к `MainActivity`

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: Лучше все-таки передать интерфейс.

Comment: @Flippy, суть не в интерфейсе, их тоже можно наинстансить в коде сколько надо. Суть что автор, как мне кажется, так и не понял, что его Презентер получает события из одной активити, а пытается управлять ее зомбо-копией :)